# JMeter requests per second validation/assertion

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing

How can I make a test fail when the request per seconds are e.g. below 20 requests?

How do I need to set up the Throughput controller?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. this is not a homework site, Please Try yourself and show us where you are wrong, may be some one help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not about Throughput controller but about [Constant Throughput Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer). You can setup this timer to provide you throughput 20reqs/s. Use Duration assertion or Response assertion to check Response times or Error codes of results.

Or you can write your own assertion in JSR223 Assertion component.

Or you can try SmartMeter's [acceptance criteria](https://www.smartmeter.io/blog/evaluate-tests-automatically-acceptance-criteria) to check your results after test.